# UITabbarController dismiss modal UINavigationController

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, modalviewcontroller, dismiss

I got a very interesting problem here. My iPhone app has an UITabbarController as rootViewController in the AppDelegate.

If the app is opened the first time, it must be configured basically. For this purpose I create an UINavigationController and tell the tabbarController to present it modally:

```
firstRun = [[firstRunViewController alloc] init];
navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstRun];
[[self tabBarController] presentModalViewController:navCtrl animated:NO];
```

When the configuration is done, I'd like to get rid of the firstRunViewController. I'm using this technique very often, using `-dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:`.

But in this constellation this doesn't work. It doesn't matter from what controller I'm calling the dismiss.
I tried it via the tabbarController, the rootViewController, the currently active viewController, of cause self and several other controllers.

EVERY TIME I call `-dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:` I get this exception:

```
'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'presentedViewController for controller is itself on dismiss for: <UINavigationController:…
```

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance, with kind regards, Julian

**EDIT**
In my AppDelegate I'm using a UITabbarController as rootViewController for the main window:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Then I'm creating an UINavigationController and tell the UITabbarController to present the modalViewController:

```
UINavigationController *navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstRun];
[[self tabBarController] presentModalViewController:navCtrl animated:NO];
```

When I now call -dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: on the firstViewController I'm getting the error from above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself!
I just couldn't see the wood for the trees! I'm quite happy right now! :)

I did really silly things: In the last viewController of the setup viewControllers I had to change the tabars viewControllers corresponding to whether the user is administrator or not. So I did:

```
appDelegate.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:appDelegate.readState,
                                                appDelegate.navCtrl,
                                                appDelegate.settings, nil];
```

You can see that I was adding the AppDelegate's "navCtrl" to the tabbar's viewControllers. So I was trying to dismiss a viewController I just added to the parentViewControllers (UITabbarController) sub-controllers.

Dismissing something I want to present just in the same moment is NOT advisable! :))

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you are abusing UITabbarController. This class, even though a subclass of UIViewController, does not really use much of the UIViewController infrastructure.

What you want is a slight extension of what you have now. Create a new UIViewController subclass in your appDelegate, and add it as the single object to an array, and set the tabBar's viewControllers to this array. Set your subclass' hidesBottomBarWhenPushed to YES so it hides the tab bar when it becomes visible.

Now your app will launch and your UIViewController subclass will become the frontmost view. You can make this view the one you wanted to present modally, or you can present that view from your subclass using some kind of animation. Oh, and if you use the launch view as the background image for your subclass, you can really make this a smooth transition - I do this now.

When your modal view is done, then you can instantiate whatever views you want to then display, and set the UITabBarController to use those views with tabBarController.viewControllers (or the animated version). Poof, you UIViewController will get replaces (and under ARC just disappear).

Comment: This kind of works… But I can't apply animations then. I tried to add [UIView animateWithDuratio:] on the last modal viewController. But the animations just don't show up.

Comment: I really want to understand what the problem is. Because I'm presenting a modalViewController (daily business) like I do, when I present my login-viewController. I think the problem is the one instance more, the navigationController...

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a chance to test my hypothesis, but I suspect that this issue could depend on the fact that you are presenting the modal view too early, whereby too early means before the main window has had the chance to set up the tab bar controller. So, I would suggest this changes:

1. create a method to instantiate your navigation controller:

   ```
   - (void)initializeAndPresentNavigationController {
     UINavigationController *navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstRun];
     [[self tabBarController] presentModalViewController:navCtrl animated:NO];
   }
   ```
2. instead of presenting the navigation controller directly from appDidFinishLaunching, call the above method asynchronously:

   ```
   [self performSelector:@selector(initializeAndPresentNavigationController) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
   ```

Here the trick of calling the method as I do in 2 is that the call to `initializeAndPresentNavigationController` will be simply pushed on the main loop, and executed after your app has had the possibility to build its initial UI.

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Hey sergio! Thanks for your help. But this solution didn't work. It results in the same error **presentedViewController for controller is itself on dismiss for:**