# Creating a logout button on iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, nsuserdefaults

I have an app using storyboard. The layout is: Nav Controller > Login View Controller > Tab Bar Controller and each tab has a Nav Controller pointing to the UIViewController for that tab. I'm trying to create a log out button that would remove the TabBarController and go back to the Login View Controller. My code is as per below:

```
// In log out function
[self.tabBarController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(patchSelector) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];

-(void)patchSelector{
    [self.tabBarController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'presentedViewController for controller is itself on dismiss for
```

I tried reading the following regarding this:

[No visible interface for dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:completion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12782742/no-visible-interface-for-dismissmodalviewcontrolleranimatedcompletion)

http://www.touchthatfruit.com/viewwillappear-and-viewdidappear-not-being-ca

[UITabbarController dismiss modal UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328651/uitabbarcontroller-dismiss-modal-uinavigationcontroller)

However, none of the above helped with the error i'm getting. Is there something i'm missing in this? The error seems to indicate that the current vc is among those getting cleaned up.

Comment: FYI, you should post your EDIT - SOLVED as an answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: A better solution would be to use an unwind segue. You can then create an unwind segue action in your login view called "logout" or something. This will pop back to this controller and then run this action.

Comment: Please don't place SOLVED in the question title. If you found a solution, it should be posted as a detailed answer.  Marking the answer as accepted is the indication that it has been solved.

Comment: I did that already. I cannot mark it as solved yet. Please read the below post.

Comment: Just removed it from the question as well, but it was already placed below, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I remove my very first UINavigationController (the one before login screen) and I change the first line above to this: `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`, it works...but only if I make it a modal segue. Easiest solution. Not sure why my original issue was, but i was able to get around it this way atleast!